# Данные csv некорректно отображаются

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv

На моем пк csv файл правильно отображается, вот как:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На другом же пк, все отображается не правильно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не правильно потому что все должно быть структурировано по колонкам. На второй фотографии такого нет. В чем проблема?

Этот файл с пк где все нормально отображается(linux)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это файл где все плохо отображается(windows)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код записи в файл:

```
def write_csv(self, data):

    """ Записываем данные в csv файл """

    with open('data.csv', 'a') as file:

        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow((
            data[0],
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5]
        ))
...
# Собираю данные
data = (letter, title, done_description_one, images, description, min_number)
# И передаю
self.write_csv(data)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример текста файла (открытого, например, в блокноте). И код, которым вы создаёте этот файл.

Comment: Локаль видимо разная и в ней разный знак разделитель колонок. Укажите явно разделитель при чтении файла.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, обновил вопрос

Comment: @CrazyElf, вы про сам excel говорите? Там нужно указать разделитель?

Comment: *вы про сам excel говорите? Там нужно указать разделитель?* Несомненно.

Comment: Вот пример, как нужно открывать файл на запись https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer. Делайте  так. Добавьте `newline=''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже подсказали в комментариях, проблема не в csv файле а втом что в Windows по-умолчанию разделителем колонок в таких файлах является `;`, а вашем файле `,`.
Можно попробовать 2 способа.

1. Изменить разделитель по-умолчанию в самой Windows.  Пуск > Панель управления > Язык и региональные стандарты. На вкладке «Форматы» кликаем кнопку «Изменить этот формат…» В открывшемся окне, на вкладке «Числа» замените «Разделитель элементов списка» на нужный, т.е. символ точки с запятой (;) меняем на запятую (,).
2. Воспользоваться мастером импорта в Excel. Для того что бы заставить программу открыть csv файл с мастером импорта можно изменить расширение файла на txt и открыть его с помощью Excel. Или в самом excel перейти на вкладку "Данные" (Data) и слева выбрать пункт "Из текста" (From text) - далее выбрать нужный файл и опять же пройти шаги мастера импорта.
   В ссылках подробней
   Ссылки - "[про изменения в Windows](http://chuvyr.ru/2014/01/csv-comma-delimiter.html)" "[Про импорт в Excell](https://office-guru.ru/excel/preobrazovyvaem-csv-v-excel-kak-importirovat-faily-csv-v-elektronnye-tablicy-excel-368.html)"